# FineUploader - Chunk uploaded - Get response data for each chunk - callback

Tags: javascript, upload, callback, fine-uploader

I'm using fine uploader to upload files to my server, its a great library, config is very easy. I would like to use chunked encoding and I expect a custom response for each chunk from the server, i.e. more than just success=true or reset=true. I want to be able to perform some custom operations on each chunk (as the server does some post processing on each chunk before returning).

Ideally I need some **ChunkUploaded** event with a `onChunkUploaded` or `onSuccessfulChunkUpload` callback to allow me to get access to the response data from the server for each chunk. This could be called from `function handleSuccessfullyCompletedChunk(id, response, xhr)`.

I note that this is already done in part for S3 uploads as you get back the ETags for each uploaded part and store these etags until you call the complete upload method which includes all the part etags. It would be great if we could similar from the normal fine uploader api.

Would it be possible to get a `UploadedChunked` callback? This would give similar features to say pluploader which has a ChunkUploaded event which includes the response object.

It would be really great to have this functionality in fine uploader!

Here is a suggested patch for fineuploader-4.0.0.js;
https://gist.github.com/nightwolfzor/7192157

**EDIT**: created a pull request; https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/pull/1028

Cheers.

Comment: Let's discuss further in your PR.  I would suggest deleting your question here on SO, since it probably doesn't make sense to have this same conversation in two places.

Comment: Thanks Ray, will discuss over at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/pull/1028 Thanks!